# Combinatorics There is a tree with x nodes, some of the edge is marked.

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Each time, Matir can choose a simple path on the tree, and ask whether the path has any marked edge or not.

1) How many times of asking can guarantee the set of marked edges?

2) If Matir knows that there are exactly $\lfloor\frac {x}{2} \rfloor $ marked edges, how many times of asking can guarantee the set of marked edges?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Anyway I think the answer for **part1** is `x-1` and for **part2** is `x-2`. Its just a guess

Comment: @Lrrr How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @MeuluElisson Consider a star tree, for **part1** we don't know how many edges are marked so we have to ask about every edge and for the **part2** I can't think of a way that we could find marked edges with less than `x-2` questions